# how to compare two generic type variable?

Tags: java, data-structures, compiler-errors, compare, generic-type-argument

my program:

```
private class Node{

    private d1 val;
    private Node next;

    public Node(d1 val){
        this.val=val;
        next=null;
    }
}
```

---

public Node sorted_list(Node left,Node right) {

```
    try {
        Node result=null;
        if(left==null) {
            return right;
        }
        if(right==null) {
            return left;
        }
        if(left.val <= right.val) // here erro occurs..
        {
            result=right;
        }
    }
    catch(NumberFormatException e) {
        
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Please elaborate your question. What do you want to know? 
What is the type `d1`? If it is your own type then you can compare it using Comparable or Comparator.

Comment: use ```compareTo``` method, ```left.val.compareTo(right.val)<=0```. Note that ```val``` must implement ```Comparable```

Comment: Generally, you'll need to make your generic `E extends Comparable<E>`.

Answer (score 0):

You should implement interface java.util.Comparator.

```
public int compare(Node o1, Node o2) {
 ....
return 0; //(o1 == o2)
....
return 1; //(o1>o2)
....
return -1; //(o1<o2)
}
```

Comment: Which class should it be implemented in?
How to use it to actually compare?

Comment: In your case you should implement this interface in your custom class - Node and in this method you implement the logic - If one object is greatter than another one or they equal each other

Comment: I know how to use it when implementing `Comparable`, but please tell me how to use it when implementing `Comparator` in `Node`.

Comment: I will give it in another answer - too long

Answer (score 0):

Just in case. You can delete "static". It was just for a demo purpose

```
public static void main(String[] args)
 {
     Node t1 = new Node(990);
     Node t2 = new Node(100);

    Node t3 = new Node(1000);
    List<Node> col = new ArrayList<>();
    col.add(t1);
    col.add(t2);
    col.add(t3);
    col.add(new Node(500));
    col.add(new Node(90));


    NodeComperator nodeComperator = new NodeComperator();
    Collections.sort(col,nodeComperator);

    for (Node nn: col
         ) {
        System.out.println(nn.num_1);
    }
}

static class NodeComperator implements Comparator<Node>
{

    @Override
    public int compare(Node o1, Node o2) {
            if (o1.num_1 > o2.num_1)
                return 1;
            if (o1.num_1 == o2.num_1)
                return 0;
            if (o1.num_1 < o2.num_1)
                return -1;
            return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public Comparator<Node> reversed() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Comparator<Node> thenComparing(Comparator<? super Node> other) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public <U> Comparator<Node> thenComparing(Function<? super Node, ? extends U> keyExtractor, Comparator<? super U> keyComparator) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public <U extends Comparable<? super U>> Comparator<Node> thenComparing(Function<? super Node, ? extends U> keyExtractor) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Comparator<Node> thenComparingInt(ToIntFunction<? super Node> keyExtractor) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Comparator<Node> thenComparingLong(ToLongFunction<? super Node> keyExtractor) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Comparator<Node> thenComparingDouble(ToDoubleFunction<? super Node> keyExtractor) {
        return null;
    }
}

static class Node
{

    private Integer num_1;

    public Node(Integer num_1) {
        this.num_1 = num_1;
    }
}
```